# YouTube not showing as a referrer?

Tags: php, youtube, http-headers

I've been tracking referrers to my site and storing it a session to be used in some reports when they do certain actions.

To get the referrer, I just do `$_SESSION["s1"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`

It seems to work for everything except YouTube. Clicking a link on YouTube generates a blank referrer. What could cause this? Does YouTube do something to the headers? Does opening a new window lose the referrer info?

Comment: Are you using `https://` when browsing YouTube?  Referers will not be sent if on https.

Comment: Referers cannot be trusted. While they can be useful, you should not DEPEND on their presence (or truthfulness).

Comment: @drew010 Nope, not using https

Comment: @MarcB Ya, I'm aware, it's just for getting an idea on where users are coming from

Comment: @MotiveKyle In that case, I'm not sure.  If you can provide a URL or alternative URL that has the same behavior I can look.  Perhaps they use Javascript to handle the link click.  Basically its up to the browser, there isn't anything YouTube could do to say "don't send an http referer" (aside from uncoventional scripting or redirect methods).

Comment: This doesn't send referrer info: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv9eNtI2PmQ&list=UU33wWg9sobEVLJNveu4QhGA&index=3&feature=plcp

Comment: I see a nofollow, but that's just for bots right?

Comment: Right, the equivalent for browsers would be `rel="noreferrer"`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same issue today. Even though this question is 5 years old it came up first on Google when I searched for the cause; so I am going to answer it here for others who stumble across it.

The issue is not so much related to YouTube and is actually caused by the browser. Some browsers will remove the `referer` header when traffic switches protocols from HTTPS to HTTP. To maintain the `referer` header you would have to link it to a URI that uses HTTPS as its protocol.

Comment: hi even if the protocol is HTTPS it does not work. the referrer is always empty in chrome and firefox because youtube does redirect to a new tab and opens new tab with about:blank.