# Log File does not save access from YouTube

Tags: youtube, logfile

i made some YouTube videos with a link to my website in the description area.
When i read the log files from my website, there is no access from youtube.
I tried it with links on other websites, every single link is listed in my logfile summary, but not youtube (i have clicked on the link very often).

My YouTube channel has links to my website since a few month and at least i clicked on the link in the description area. Why is YouTube not listed?

Thx, Jens

Comment: Are you referring to the `Referer:` header?

Comment: Sorry i dont get what you mean, what is the 'Referer: header'?

I opened my logfiles with "deep log analyzer", there is no YouTube in the Referral Summary.
When i open my logfiles with an editor, there is no youtube either

Comment: xx.xx.xx - - [18/Jun/2015:13:39:00 +0200] "GET /de/online-shop/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37348 www.meine-seite.de "https://www.facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36" "-"

xx.xx.xx - - [18/Jun/2015:13:39:03 +0200] "GET /de/online-shop/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37348 www.meine-seite.de "-                                      " "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36" "-"

Here are two entries,once i clicked on my facebook link, once on YT, why does yt write "-"

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391107/youtube-not-showing-as-a-referrer without a solution. HTTPS to HTTP is not working, but Facebook is HTTPS an it works :/